# Alpine Js template x-for renders list of objects wrongly

Tags: javascript, html, flask, alpine.js

I have a web page that I have to display a list of elements in a table,

It is a flask app.
I use alpine js cdn, tailwind css. Most of the functionality is in an external js file not on the html file.

I use x-data on body since a lot of components use appState variable `<body x-data="initData()" class="h-screen w-screen">`

I try to keep all javascript in an external file.

I declare appState like this in that file:

```
window.appState = {
    sepet: [

    ],  // This will be an array of products
    genelIskonto: (0).toFixed(2),
    iskontoTutar: (0).toFixed(2),
    toplamTutar: (0).toFixed(2),
    odenecekTutar: (0).toFixed(2),
    belgeNo: "0",
    customer: {}
};


function initData() {
    return {showSearch: false, showNavbar: true, appState: window.appState};
}
```

I have a function to add items to the list "appState.sepet" in the js file

```
function addToSepet(data) {
    console.log(data);
    item = {
        stokKodu: data.stokKodu,
        isim: data.stokKodu + " " + data.stokAdi,
        fiyat: data.fiyat,
        adet: 1,
        birim: data.birim,
        iskonto: 0,
        netTutar: data.fiyat.toFixed(2),
    }
    let existing = false;
    for (const existingItem of window.appState.sepet) {
        console.log("Check", existingItem.isim)
        if (item.isim === existingItem.isim) {
            existingItem.adet++;
            existingItem.netTutar = ((existingItem.fiyat * existingItem.adet) * (1 - (existingItem.iskonto / 100))).toFixed(2);
            existing = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log("Check", existing);
    if (!existing) {
        console.log("Push new")
        window.appState.sepet.push(item);
    }
    let tableElement = document.querySelector('[x-ref="tableBody"]'); // Replace with your table's id or selector
    tableElement.innerHTML = tableElement.innerHTML;
}
```

The last line was needed because for some reason alpine js didn't react to data  change.

This is the table body code in the html file:

```
<tbody x-ref="tableBody">
  <template x-for="(item, index) in appState.sepet" :key="index">
    <tr class="kalemBilgileriRow even" x-init="console.log('Row Creation:',item)">
      <td x-text="item.isim" class="text-left"></td>
      <td x-text="item.fiyat" class="text-left"></td>
      <td x-text="item.adet" class="text-left"></td>
      <td x-text="item.birim" class="text-left"></td>
      <td x-text="item.iskonto" class="text-left"><input class="input"></td>
      <td x-text="item.netTutar"></td>
      <td>
      <div class="flex justify-center items-center"><svg I removed svg code but it works properly/></svg></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

I use the console log to add items to appState.sepet using addToSepet function,
The expected behavior is:

When an item is added check if it is a duplicate (item.isim must be unique), if it is unique just add it to table, if it is not increment the item.adet value for that item.isim without adding the duplicate item.

Checking with alpine js dev tools extension I confirmed that appState.sepet is being updated as expected. But error arises when we look at the rendering.

Steps to replicate:

1. run addToSepet({stokKodu:"id1", stokAdi:"x", fiyat:1.00,birim:"adet"}); table looks correct, there is only one row with correct info
2. run addToSepet with the same arguments; Now the table has two rows, both have the same value for item.isim, and one row has the correct amount (item.adet = 2) and other row says amount (item.adet) = 1; I check through alpine js dev tools and can't find two elements in the list, there is only one element in the list with the correct amount, I log window.appState.sepet and it is correct again.
3. This is where it gets interesting,
   run addToSepet({stokKodu:"id2", stokAdi:"x", fiyat:1.00,birim:"adet"});

Table now has 4 rows, first two are the correctly displayed ones, with correct item.adet values and id's,
but now there are 2 extra rows, both displaying the newly added id2 element with item.adet = 1, the buggy row in step 2 doesn't even exist now.

I log the row creation with x-init="console.log(item)" as you can see int he html code,

This is the whole log,

```
addToSepet({stokKodu:"id1", stokAdi:"x", fiyat:1.00,birim:"adet"});
state_perakende.js:24 {stokKodu: 'id1', stokAdi: 'x', fiyat: 1, birim: 'adet'}
state_perakende.js:44 Check false
state_perakende.js:46 Push new
VM2415:3 Row Creation: Proxy(Object) {stokKodu: 'id1', isim: 'id1 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 1, birim: 'adet', …}
undefined
addToSepet({stokKodu:"id1", stokAdi:"x", fiyat:1.00,birim:"adet"});
state_perakende.js:24 {stokKodu: 'id1', stokAdi: 'x', fiyat: 1, birim: 'adet'}
state_perakende.js:36 Check id1 x
state_perakende.js:44 Check true
VM2415:3 Row Creation: Proxy(Object) {stokKodu: 'id1', isim: 'id1 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 2, birim: 'adet', …}
VM2415:3 Row Creation: {stokKodu: 'id1', isim: 'id1 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 1, birim: 'adet', …}
undefined
addToSepet({stokKodu:"id2", stokAdi:"x", fiyat:1.00,birim:"adet"});
state_perakende.js:24 {stokKodu: 'id2', stokAdi: 'x', fiyat: 1, birim: 'adet'}
state_perakende.js:36 Check id1 x
state_perakende.js:44 Check false
state_perakende.js:46 Push new
VM2415:3 Row Creation: Proxy(Object) {stokKodu: 'id1', isim: 'id1 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 2, birim: 'adet', …}
VM2415:3 Row Creation: Proxy(Object) {stokKodu: 'id2', isim: 'id2 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 1, birim: 'adet', …}
VM2415:3 Row Creation: {stokKodu: 'id2', isim: 'id2 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 1, birim: 'adet', …}
VM2415:3 Row Creation: {stokKodu: 'id2', isim: 'id2 x', fiyat: 1, adet: 1, birim: 'adet', …}
undefined
```

I know that alpine js wraps objects with Proxy but I don't get how there are plain js objects logged in the template. At each step I am sure appState.sepet has only the info that can generate the Proxied objects, other rows are the issue I am experiencing. I couldn't find a way to resolve this. If there are additional debugging steps I must make please let me know.

Thank you

I tried different methods to access the list, none of them behaved differently, also alpine js dev tools extension confirms that the data is as expected. The issue is most probably about rendering.

I couldn't find anyone experiencing this issue on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are interacting with Alpine is a bit atypical.
I suggest you to save the data of the basket in the *"Alpine's storage"*, this allows also the automatic rendering of the new rows when the data changes:

```html
<tbody>
   <template x-for="(item) in $store.basket.items"">
      <!--your html-->
   </template>
</tbody>

<script>

function initData() {
   return {showSearch: false, showNavbar: true};
}

function addToSepet(data) {
  
    const item = {   // note the 'const' here

        stokKodu: data.stokKodu,
        isim: data.stokKodu + " " + data.stokAdi,
        fiyat: data.fiyat,
        adet: 1,
        birim: data.birim,
        iskonto: 0,
        netTutar: data.fiyat.toFixed(2),
    }

    const existingItem = Alpine.store('basket').items.find(o => o.isim === item.isim);

    if (typeof existingItem !== "undefined") {
        existingItem.adet++;
        existingItem.netTutar = ((existingItem.fiyat * existingItem.adet) * (1 - (existingItem.iskonto / 100))).toFixed(2);
    }
    else {
        Alpine.store('basket').items.push(item);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {

    Alpine.store('basket', {
        items: [],
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the best practice input, I have seen why handling global states in the store is better. I applied the steps that you provided, however the issue changed but is not gone.

After I made the changes buggy rows still appear, but they are empty,

and the log in x-init that I have shown in the original question tries to log item, but I get error item is not defined. I could not find any meaning to this, the array as I log it is at length 3 but I see 5-6 rows. The extra rows all raise errors since item is not defined. How can this happen if we are iterating with through items?

Comment: You must remove the `tableElement.innerHTML = tableElement.innerHTML;`: it's not needed and it's the cause of your problems.